# Radeon HD mobility driver 13.1 Install

Tags: installation, drivers, 13.04, ati, radeon

Looking to install the Radeon HD mobility driver 13.1 on Ubuntu 13.04

Looking to install this driver:
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx

Is it the same install as suggested [here for 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/286775#286775)?

New to Ubuntu and upon initial install I lost unity, seeing only my background.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Because I think that is very clear the difference between each versions, one is 13.1 and the other is 13.04

Comment: 13.1 is the revised AMD driver, whilst 13.04 is the ubuntu version.

From the link for the driver install on ubuntu is the 13.4 for what I assume is for the 13.4 drivers, which is for the newer cards.

I would guess that installation is the same, although I don't want to do end up messing it up again.

Answer (score 0):

This repository provides AMD Catalyst Lagacy 13.1 (fglrx 8.97.100.7) drivers for Radeon HD 2xxx - 4xxx for Ubuntu:
12.04 Precise Pangolin
12.10 Quantal Quetzal
13.04 Raring Ringtail

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04.2 make sure you got linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal package installed.

If you are using Ubuntu 13.04 the driver might not work very well with Unity. If that the case please consider resetting Unity configuration to default or use other DE.

To use Catalyst Legacy 13.1 you need to do following commands:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy

And restart your computer.

Credit for answer goes to Tomasz Makarewicz
Original post: https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx